# I saved a to do list, how can I load it onto my to do list app?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

-This is my code:

```
private void loadList() {
        try {
            List tasks = (List) Reader.readTasks(new File(SAVE_DESTINATION));
            String firstTask = tasks.getItem(0);
            listModel.addElement(firstTask);

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to load tasks from " + SAVE_DESTINATION);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

-I am getting this error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.awt.List

- (My saved list will be longer than 1 item long, above I was trying to see if I could at least get the first element in the list to load up.)
- I have already got save working so I can save a to do list. I want to be able to load the saved to do list when the program starts. Can anyone help??

Comment: Yes, change your import from `java.awt.List` to `java.util.List`

Comment: or be much more specific in your casting: `java.util.List tasks = (java.util.List) Reader.readTasks(new File(SAVE_DESTINATION));`

Comment: this is what I am getting now, any suggestion would be greatly appreciated: 

- Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: private void loadList() {
        try {
            List<Task> tasks = Reader.readTasks(new File(SAVE_DESTINATION));
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
                listModel.addElement(tasks.get(i).toString());
            }
            PlayMusic playMusic = new PlayMusic(LOAD_TASK_SOUND);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Loaded From: " + SAVE_DESTINATION);

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to load tasks from " + SAVE_DESTINATION);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: it is weird because im only getting that error sometimes...